# How do I exclude AndroidTest/assets from Gradle builds when not testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, android-assets

My unit tests require some large assets in order to test parsing complex media files. I'm noticing that Gradle includes the entire androidTest/assets folder in both debug and release builds. This is resulting in needless APK file size bloat.

I tried setting android { aaptOptions { ignoreAssetsPattern "!*.ext"} } in build.gradle for the media files' extension, but the androidTest/assets folder does not appear to honor these asset exclusion options. I managed to get the build to specifically exclude each file one by one using android { packagingOption { exclude 'AndroidTest/assets/filename.ext' } } where filename.ext is the full filename with no wildcard support. This excludes the assets from all builds, even when testing.

I expect I can find some Gradle way to exclude the folder in release builds, but the assets probably shouldn't appear in a build unless I intend to use it specifically for running instrumentation tests. Is there any good option here?

I simply cannot believe the default behavior is to include androidTest/assets in all builds all of the time. Should this be considered a bug and be reported?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I just dropped an `assets/` folder into `androidTest/` of a project, put a 1.3MB file in there, ran **`gradle clean assembleDebug`** on the project, and the resulting `...-debug.apk` does not contain the file. Do you have a sample project that reproduces your findings?

Comment: I located my test assets in <module>/src/androidTest/assets. Only the assets are being included and none of the test source files in the same androidTest directory. Are your tests seeing the assets you included? If the assets weren't available to be used by the tests, that would not be a useful solution.

Comment: "Are your tests seeing the assets you included?" -- I have no idea, as that does not really matter for the purposes of my comment. You wrote "all builds", which IMHO would include the debug and release versions of the APK, not just the tests. If you have a different definition of "all builds", you may wish to to clarify your question. If, OTOH, you do mean that the debug and release APKs contain your assets, as I cannot reproduce this effect, it would not appear to be the case that "the default behavior is to include androidTest/assets in all builds all of the time".

Comment: This is why I asked if you have a sample project that reproduces your findings. If others can independently verify this behavior, then perhaps it is a bug, and we can report it (the tools team is pretty good about bugs).

Comment: I need a way to perform instrument tests with assets without them ending up in releases. When the assets are placed in a location where they're available to the test, they seem to also be included in all APKs. I'll have to create a new project which reproduces this, as I will not post client code. I'll comment back when I've done this. (BTW Mark, it was nice to meet you at AnDevCon.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems another developer explicitly added a directive to my build.gradle file after I wrote tests for my library project. He changed the default location to look for instrument tests. As a result, the Gradle tools treated the androidTest/assets folder as a normal assets folder and added the files to every APK.

Here was the offending line:

```
instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
```

Thanks for your help!